# Registry, DCOM and Windows 2008/2012 64 bit

Tags: registry, windows-server-2008-r2, dcom

I have a COM dll which was created ages ago - it has .odl file and not .idl file. I want to create it's *remote* instance on Windows 2008/2012 64 bit. It originally did not create AppID registry key so I created a reg file which will create AppID key for the class in the DLL. I tested it on windows 2003 32 bit and it works fine when I try to create the object remotely. But on Windows 2008/2012 64 bit, even with no UAC I don't seem to be able to create the object remotely. I keep on getting "class not registered" error but I can create object locally. So, I wanted to know where and what registry entries that I need to make so that I can remotely create the object.

Thanks for your help,
-Neel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make entries for AppID under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\AppID node instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID